# When I press the power button to start my laptop, why does it always shows a gray screen filled with coloured dots?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, ssd, lenovo-laptop

When I press the power button to start my laptop, why does it always shows a gray screen filled with coloured dots?

I have Windows 10 Lenovo laptop with SSD, about 2 years old.

Only recently (since last month), when I press the power button to start the laptop, it shows a gray screen filled with coloured dots. After getting annoyed by this issue I have re-installed Windows 10 and all updates, but the issue still persists.

When this happens, there is no way to proceed further so I have to press and hold the power button to force shutdown. Then after it is switched off, I press the power button again and this time it starts OK.

What could be the problem and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the Graphics chip has a problem. It could be another cause as well, but the Graphics chip seems most likely.

When it is running properly, do the following:

1. Run the Lenovo Update and Drivers app (Control Panel). Allow this to update all Drivers (BIOS, Chipset, Video and all others).
2. From the Lenovo Support Site, get the Lenovo Diagnostics App, download it, install it and run it. Do all tests and see what hardware issues it finds.

These are the two main things you can do.